# A tense problem about an auto reply model

Tags: tenses

I want to set an auto reply model when I'm holding an online chat room and dealing with some other things. Which of the following is correct:

1)If I didn't say hi, it means I am working.

2)If I haven't said hi, it means I am working.

3)If I don't say hi, it means I am working.

Comment: They're all fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are indeed all understandable and acceptable. If we pursue the implications fastidiously, we can find small differences that, in practice, do not matter. Let’s try ...

1. When did you did not say Hi? When a user tried to chat to you? At some time you are thinking of but not the time the user chatted? At the moment the user is reading the site? And in any case, in a chat room you generally will have said hi at some time, so there is altogether some doubt as to when, or even if you did not, say hi.
2. Much the same analysis as 1.
3. Is a plain statement that covers all past, present and future modes of your behaviour, with no overtones of time or of confusion with the times you previously said hi.

In conclusion, I prefer 3 but for all normal usage it really does not matter which you use.

Comment: Down-marker, please explain what you disagree with.